# Access template variable inside component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I ran into an issue with ng-template.

We are passing some parameters via ngTemplateOutletContext like below in a table component. We use different renderers for the cells depending on the type of data contained inside. Notice the cellvalue parameter as it is what I need.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="useCellRenderer(column, row)">
   <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.renderer.templateref" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ cellvalue: row[column.attr], rowvalue:row }">
   </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

The template of the component in charge of the rendering looks as follows:

```
<ng-template #templateRef let-cellvalue="cellvalue" let-rowvalue="rowvalue">
  {{ getTraslateValue(cellvalue)}}
</ng-template>
```

The template is able to access the cellvalue parameter and call the function correctly, but I want to access the same parameter from the component's TS and can't seem to be able to do it.

What I've tried so far goes along the line of the following snippet

```
@ViewChild('templateRef', { read: TemplateRef })
  public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.templateref.elementRef);
  }
```

But cellvalue is nowhere to be found in the console.log

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: Nope, no errors, just no way to access the data that I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So @SebOlens has guided me to the solution with what he said. I ended creating a directive with exportAs. The directive is as follows:

TS

```
@Directive({ selector: '[exposeVariable]', exportAs: 'exposed' })
export class ExposeVariableDirective {
  @Input() variablesToExpose: any;
  }
}
```

It can be used in the template in the following way for example:

HTML

```
<ng-template #templateRef let-cellvalue="cellvalue" let-rowvalue="rowvalue">
  <div exposeVariable [variablesToExpose]="{cellValue: cellvalue}" #exposedRef="exposed">
    {{ getTraslateValue(cellvalue)}}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And the cellvalue can be accessed from the component:

TS

```
@ViewChild('exposedRef') public directiveExposed: any;
```

In my case the directive inits after the `AfterViewInit` of the component, so if you try to initialise something you will have to either watch the value of the `ViewChild` variable or, in my case, I did a component activated with an `ngIf` and a exposed variable from the template so I could use the hooks from the new component.

Thanks again @SebOlens :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) Don't forget to upvote the answer

Comment: Done, sorry I forgot :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is not an answer just a suggestion so please do not minus it if it doesn't work.

Have you tried something like that ?

html

```
<ng-template #cellValue="cellvalue" let-cellvalue="cellvalue" let-rowvalue="rowvalue">
  {{ getTraslateValue(cellvalue)}}
</ng-template>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('cellValue') public cellValue: any;
```

I'm not sure if it's going to work cause constructions like `#cellValue="cellvalue"` work only with directives which have `exportAs` description in their decorators

This is not going to work:

```
@ViewChild('templateRef', { read: TemplateRef })
  public templateref: TemplateRef<any>;
```

because it references the template itself not the generated part of dom. 
Maybe try referencing the part of the dom which is generated by the template.

Comment: As you said, your first solution won't work because it isn't a directive with `exporAs`.
I've tried accessing like this and returns undefined:
HTML
`<ng-template #templateRef let-cellvalue="cellvalue" let-rowvalue="rowvalue">
  <div #test>test</div>
  {{ getTraslateValue(cellvalue)}}
</ng-template>`

TS
`@ViewChild('test', { read: TemplateRef })
  public cellValue: any;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.cellValue);
  }`
Sorry for the code formatting :S

Comment: you can always make a directive with exportAs, assing cellvalue to it and then reference it like I did.

Comment: also don't read TemplateRef of an object which isn't a template, read ViewContainerRef or ElementRef.